Can I make my SwiftUI View aware of the circumstances that caused an update to a @Binding property?
Summary
I'm using SwiftUI to synchronize a property on a View with an observable object, but I'm losing critical details about the origin of the updates that get sent from the observable object to the View.
Description
I have an app with an observable singleton data store, which is the source of truth for any view that displays the contents of the store. One of its properties, things, is a dictionary of instances: [String: Thing]. When a Thing changes due to a message received from the network, I have to show that change in views that rely on the store, and when the Thing changes from local input, I have to propagate that change to other apps over the network. To forward local changes to the network, I use an onChange listener. I use SwiftUI's @State and @Binding to keep the store and the Views in sync. This works well when I'm handling updates from the keyboard. However, the problem I run into handling updates from the network is this:
When the store receives a network message, it makes a change to things and this is reflected in the ThingView. Then ThingView detects a change to the thing.value, and broadcasts this change back to the network.
Problem
The app checks the originId of incoming messages, and ignores ones whose id match its own. However, when SwiftUI carries an update to the ThingView, the originId of the message is erased. ThingView has no way of knowing that this update came from the network, so it triggers a rebroadcast as if the change originated locally. Is there a way to get around this while still using SwiftUI?
I was thinking that old-fashioned pub-sub pipes with Combine might be more flexible and readable, and I could implement them such that I keep my originId available when I process updates to the ThingView. But before I do that I would like to know what others think.
Code
@Observable
class Thing: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var value: String
}

@Observable
class ThingStore {
    static let shared = ThingStore
    let originId = UUID()
    var things: [String: Thing]
    
    func broadcastUpdate(thing: Thing, value: String) { ... }
    
    func handleUpdateMessage(originId: String, thing: Thing) {
        guard originId != self.originId { return }
        
        self.things[thing.id] = thing
    }
}

struct ThingsView {
    @State var thingStore = ThingStore.shared

    var body: some View {
        List($thingStore.values) { $thing in
            ThingView(thing: $thing)
        }
    }
}

struct ThingView {
    @Binding var thing

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $thing.value)
            .onChange(of: thing.value) {
                ThingStore.broadcastUpdate(thing, thing.value)
            }
        }
    }
}


I don't think you should be using .onChange for this, instead you probably need some other non-UI controller object that observes the model and transmits the changes, probably with some kind of throttle.

Note, you should not use List($thingStore.values) { $thing in...} and @Binding var thing in ThingView,
binding is for value types (struct) not reference types (class).
You should be using @Bindable var ... see: Bindable
and Managing Data

Thanks @malhal, I moved the custom update handling to the model (letting Thing act as it's own controller for now), and now I can control changes to it with more precision. Thank you too workingdog (can't @ you for some reason), I made it @Bindable.

In Thing, you could keep track of where the last update came from.
enum ChangeOrigin {
 case local, network
}

@Observable
class Thing: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var value: String
    var latestChangeOrigin: ChangeOrigin
}

Then, when you get an update from the network:
func handleUpdateMessage(thing: Thing) {        
    self.things[thing.id].value = thing.value
    self.things[thing.id].latestChangeOrigin = .network
}

And when user updates locally:
.onChange(of: thing.value) {
    if thing.latestChangeOrigin == .network {
        thing.latestChangeOrigin = .local
        return
    }
    ThingStore.broadcastUpdate(thing, thing.value)
}


Thanks for the idea, but I just couldn't find a way to make it work in my program
